# Please Help Me to Understand This Sentence

Tags: sentence, subcontinental-english

> Development engineers will embrace the emphasis on early demonstrations and ability to assess and evaluate performance tradeoff in subsequent releases

Answer (score 1):

It means that development engineers will appreciate the stress that is, or will be, given on demonstrations done in advance and also the skill to calculate and judge the performance trade-off (*trade-off means to sacrifice something in order to gain something else*) in future releases.

P.S. you could simply use a dictionary or just google the words to understand their meaning instead of posting it here